# How can I filter on Join in JPQL RestRepository

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have this mapping in a `Country` class:

```
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@OneToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Map<I18nLang, BasicProperties> fields = new HashMap<I18nLang, BasicProperties>();
```

`I18nLang` is an Enumeration
Then, I have this in `CountryRepository`:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Country c JOIN c.fields f where KEY(f) = :lang")
public List<Country> findAllFilteredByLang(@Param("lang") I18nLang lang);
```

The result is for the url: http://localhost:8080/mmt/api/countries/search/findAllFilteredByLang?lang=EN:

```
"countries": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "fields": {
          "FR": {
            "libelle": null,
            "description": "",
            "smallDescription": null
          },
          "JP": {
            "libelle": null,
            "description": "",
            "smallDescription": null
          },
          "EN": {
            "libelle": "dz",
            "description": "<p>dzdz</p>",
            "smallDescription": null
          },
          "CN": {
            "libelle": null,
            "description": "",
            "smallDescription": null
          }
        }
    ....
```

Is it possible with JPQL to have the response with only the EN field displaying in the answer?:
I also tried this query
`SELECT c FROM Country c LEFT JOIN c.fields f ON KEY(f) = :lang`
but it does the same

```
"countries": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "fields": {
          "EN": {
            "libelle": "dz",
            "description": "<p>dzdz</p>",
            "smallDescription": null
          }
        }
    ....
```

Here are the logs, as you can see, we have a first Query returning the right `BasicProperties` on requested key "EN". Then we have annother request getting everything back...

```
Hibernate: select country0_.id as id1_10_, country0_.code as code2_10_ from country country0_ left outer join  (country_fields fields1_ left outer join basic_properties basicprope2_ on fields1_.fields_id=basicprope2_.id) on country0_.id=fields1_.country_id and (fields1_.fields_key=?)
2020-04-13 09:44:06.533 TRACE 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [EN]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 0
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row: EntityKey[com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country#2]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 1
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row: EntityKey[com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country#1]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving attributes for [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country#2]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `fields` : value = NOT NULL COLLECTION
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`fields`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `cities` : value = NOT NULL COLLECTION
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`cities`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `code` : value = aaa
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`code`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Done materializing entity [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country#2]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving attributes for [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country#1]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `fields` : value = NOT NULL COLLECTION
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`fields`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `cities` : value = NOT NULL COLLECTION
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`cities`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `code` : value = CNA
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`code`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.537 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Done materializing entity [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country#1]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.538 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction commit
2020-04-13 09:44:06.538 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1347464982<open>)]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.538 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
2020-04-13 09:44:06.538 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing flush-time cascades
2020-04-13 09:44:06.538 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Dirty checking collections
2020-04-13 09:44:06.538 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  : Collection found: [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.fields#2], was: [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.fields#2] (uninitialized)
2020-04-13 09:44:06.538 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  : Collection found: [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.cities#2], was: [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.cities#2] (uninitialized)
2020-04-13 09:44:06.538 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  : Collection found: [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.fields#1], was: [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.fields#1] (uninitialized)
2020-04-13 09:44:06.538 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  : Collection found: [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.cities#1], was: [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.cities#1] (uninitialized)
2020-04-13 09:44:06.538 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 2 objects
2020-04-13 09:44:06.538 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 4 collections
2020-04-13 09:44:06.538 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : Listing entities:
2020-04-13 09:44:06.538 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country{code=aaa, cities=<uninitialized>, id=2, fields=<uninitialized>}
2020-04-13 09:44:06.538 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country{code=CNA, cities=<uninitialized>, id=1, fields=<uninitialized>}
2020-04-13 09:44:06.539 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
2020-04-13 09:44:06.540 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/hal+json', given [*/*] and supported [application/hal+json]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.540 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [Resources { content: [Resource { content: com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country@6851e9ae, links: [<ht (truncated)...]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.541 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.d.r.w.j.PersistentEntityJackson2Module : Serializing PersistentEntity org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl@2aea90f9.
2020-04-13 09:44:06.541 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] stractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer : Loading collection: [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.fields#2]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.541 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select fields0_.country_id as country_1_11_0_, fields0_.fields_id as fields_i2_11_0_, fields0_.fields_key as fields_k3_0_, basicprope1_.id as id1_7_1_, basicprope1_.description as descript2_7_1_, basicprope1_.libelle as libelle3_7_1_, basicprope1_.small_description as small_de4_7_1_ from country_fields fields0_ inner join basic_properties basicprope1_ on fields0_.fields_id=basicprope1_.id where fields0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select fields0_.country_id as country_1_11_0_, fields0_.fields_id as fields_i2_11_0_, fields0_.fields_key as fields_k3_0_, basicprope1_.id as id1_7_1_, basicprope1_.description as descript2_7_1_, basicprope1_.libelle as libelle3_7_1_, basicprope1_.small_description as small_de4_7_1_ from country_fields fields0_ inner join basic_properties basicprope1_ on fields0_.fields_id=basicprope1_.id where fields0_.country_id=?
2020-04-13 09:44:06.542 TRACE 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [2]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.542 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Preparing collection initializer : [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.fields#2]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.543 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] e.p.i.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl : Found row of collection: [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.fields#2]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.543 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] e.p.i.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl : Found row of collection: [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.fields#2]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.543 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] e.p.i.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl : Found row of collection: [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.fields#2]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.543 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] e.p.i.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl : Found row of collection: [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.fields#2]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.543 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] e.p.i.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl : Found row of collection: [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.fields#2]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.543 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving attributes for [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.BasicProperties#8]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `description` : value = 
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`description`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `libelle` : value = null
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`libelle`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `smallDescription` : value = null
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`smallDescription`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Done materializing entity [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.BasicProperties#8]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving attributes for [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.BasicProperties#6]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `description` : value = 
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`description`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `libelle` : value = null
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`libelle`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `smallDescription` : value = null
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`smallDescription`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Done materializing entity [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.BasicProperties#6]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving attributes for [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.BasicProperties#7]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `description` : value = 
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`description`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `libelle` : value = null
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`libelle`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `smallDescription` : value = null
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`smallDescription`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Done materializing entity [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.BasicProperties#7]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving attributes for [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.BasicProperties#10]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `description` : value = 
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`description`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `libelle` : value = null
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`libelle`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `smallDescription` : value = null
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`smallDescription`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Done materializing entity [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.BasicProperties#10]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving attributes for [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.BasicProperties#9]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `description` : value = 
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`description`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `libelle` : value = null
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`libelle`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `smallDescription` : value = null
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`smallDescription`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Done materializing entity [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.BasicProperties#9]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : 1 collections were found in result set for role: com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.fields
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : Collection fully initialized: [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.fields#2]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : 1 collections initialized for role: com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.fields
2020-04-13 09:44:06.544 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] stractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer : Done loading collection
2020-04-13 09:44:06.545 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.d.r.w.j.PersistentEntityJackson2Module : Serializing PersistentEntity org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl@766cc4fa.
2020-04-13 09:44:06.545 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.d.r.w.j.PersistentEntityJackson2Module : Serializing PersistentEntity org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl@766cc4fa.
2020-04-13 09:44:06.545 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.d.r.w.j.PersistentEntityJackson2Module : Serializing PersistentEntity org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl@766cc4fa.
2020-04-13 09:44:06.546 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.d.r.w.j.PersistentEntityJackson2Module : Serializing PersistentEntity org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl@766cc4fa.
2020-04-13 09:44:06.546 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.d.r.w.j.PersistentEntityJackson2Module : Serializing PersistentEntity org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl@766cc4fa.
2020-04-13 09:44:06.546 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.d.r.w.j.PersistentEntityJackson2Module : Serializing PersistentEntity org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl@2aea90f9.
2020-04-13 09:44:06.547 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] stractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer : Loading collection: [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.fields#1]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.547 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select fields0_.country_id as country_1_11_0_, fields0_.fields_id as fields_i2_11_0_, fields0_.fields_key as fields_k3_0_, basicprope1_.id as id1_7_1_, basicprope1_.description as descript2_7_1_, basicprope1_.libelle as libelle3_7_1_, basicprope1_.small_description as small_de4_7_1_ from country_fields fields0_ inner join basic_properties basicprope1_ on fields0_.fields_id=basicprope1_.id where fields0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select fields0_.country_id as country_1_11_0_, fields0_.fields_id as fields_i2_11_0_, fields0_.fields_key as fields_k3_0_, basicprope1_.id as id1_7_1_, basicprope1_.description as descript2_7_1_, basicprope1_.libelle as libelle3_7_1_, basicprope1_.small_description as small_de4_7_1_ from country_fields fields0_ inner join basic_properties basicprope1_ on fields0_.fields_id=basicprope1_.id where fields0_.country_id=?
2020-04-13 09:44:06.547 TRACE 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.547 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Preparing collection initializer : [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.fields#1]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.547 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : 1 collections were found in result set for role: com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.fields
2020-04-13 09:44:06.547 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : Collection fully initialized: [com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.fields#1]
2020-04-13 09:44:06.547 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : 1 collections initialized for role: com.makemytrip.webapp.domain.Country.fields
2020-04-13 09:44:06.548 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] stractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer : Done loading collection
2020-04-13 09:44:06.549 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@3cdc6398
2020-04-13 09:44:06.549 DEBUG 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
```

Thank you by advance :)

Comment: Add BasicProperties class &  application executed query log

Comment: your query is using left join instead of inner join

Comment: @Lemmy Same problem with inner join